# How to download songs from Amazon's Cloud Player?

Tags: music, banshee, amazon-mp3-downloader

Using the latest Banshee (1.9.6) and the Amazon MP3 extension, I just bought an album, and it was copied to my Amazon Cloud Drive/Player. How do I download this to my computer? Banshee's Amazon MP3 does not seem to open the Amazon Cloud Player pages, and the Amazon Cloud Player website keeps asking me to use their downloader program (which didn't work, perhaps too old).

On a side note, I can download the files individually from the Amazon Cloud Drive website, but that is not an ideal solution. I want to click a few buttons, download the whole album at once, and import it into Banshee (like it used to, before the Cloud Drive stuff).

Comment: Amazon Music now lets you download select multiple songs to download at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .amz files downloaded from Amazon's Cloud Drive are actually (subtly) different than the .amz files downloaded from their .mp3 store.  Banshee's Amazon downloader wasn't able to recognize and open these files in Banshee 1.9.6, but [this has been fixed.](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646237)  The fix is in Banshee 2.0, which is in 11.04.

[image: Downloading Music from Amazon Cloud Player in Banshee]

Comment: Thanks James, for pointing out that in general daily builds can be unstable.  However, in this case the daily build falls between a release candidate and a stable release, so it shouldn't be any less stable than the development build the OP was already using. :)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the .amz file, but Banshee wasn't able to do anything with it. Glad to hear a fix has been released.

Comment: Added a screenshot, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `Amazon Cloud Player` for Linux, or any client for it. The only way to download music which is already purchased, and is stored in the cloud player on Amazon, is to download the songs one file at a time.

When purchasing, however, you can use the `Download your music now` link on the `Thanks for your purchase` page, which will use the classic method of downloading music via an `.amz` file, which can be used with `banshee`, `clamz`, or other downloaders that support `.amz` files.

Answer (score 2):

I found that Banshee 2.2.1 was downloading my amazon mp3s to /tmp/banshee-amz-downloader
instead of my media or downloads folder.

Unfortunately there is no setting for where to download the files :/

Anyway, if you bought music and you downloaded it and not you don't see it in your library and can't find the files - try looking in /tmp/banshee-amz-downloader

For me the files had non-sense names like ee4560889fdf09fg.mp3 but their icon was the album art.

**The best way I've found to import them:**

1).  Use banshee to download them to /tmp/banshee-amz-downloads.  I just double-clicked the .amz files and it had an option to open with banshee so I did that.  It showed a loading bar and when it finished:

2).  Change your Banshee settings from them default settings to copy imported music to media folders, and to update metadata and file and folder names: Edit->Preferences then check boxes: "Copy files to media folders when importing", and "Write metadata to files", and "Update file and folder names"

3).  Import the /tmp/banshee-amz-downloader folder's contents using Media->Import Media or by copying the folder into the music folder that Banshee is set to look in and rescan with Tools->Rescan Music Library

The end result will be copied mp3s sorted into appropriate folders in your music library with appropriate file names and metadata, and available in Banshee

Answer (score 1):

There's `clamz`, which is a command-line tool that works with AMZ files.

Comment: But where do you find the AMZ files these days?

Comment: Since Amazon decided not to support Linux AT ALL you have to convince the cloud player you're on Windows. Use the user-agent switcher plugin for Firefox to switch to IE on Windows before you load the page. And I recommend Pymazon as well now - it's significantly wife-friendlier.

Comment: Thanks spending a good deal of time reviewing all the options to automate downloading the whole album at once, I found I download the entire album one song at a time in just a minute or two. The hard way was easier.

Answer (score 1):

One graphical option is 'Pymazon'. But it's not in the Software Centre so you'd have to follow the instructions on its website to install it.

http://code.google.com/p/pymazon/

Comment: There was one in the software center that worked on 11.10 but I don't remember what the name is. If it is still there I don't know if it will work with 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small GreasMonkey Script you can use in Firefox (probably also Chrome) which will unlock the multiple song download feature on Amazon Cloud Player. You can find it here:
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/426973

The resulting file you can then open with clamz or pymazon.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working now! For me I have a **durty** workaround with firefox is

1. to download file by file while it only works when I play it directly (Save File doesn't work...)
2. and then to do a

   ```
   mv /tmp/*.mp3  /location/of/album
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to download a purchased album  from your Amazon music library through your browser (.zip, only tested in Chromium) without any special tools or workarounds. Enjoy!