# Is there an Amazon downloader for purchased music?

Tags: software-recommendation, music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to download songs from Amazon's Cloud Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33158/how-to-download-songs-from-amazons-cloud-player)

Is there an Amazon down loader for purchased music in 12.04?

There was one for 11.10 that worked but I find nothing in the software center for 12.04.

Thanks in advance. Bob.